# MobileFirst Application Centre Apple Approval

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-server, mobilefirst-cli, mobilefirst-appcenter

I have a question regarding the distribution of apps through the IBM mobilefirst app centre.

1. The mobile client would need to have an apple certificate as it will be place on the store so that users can get access to the application centre via the mobile client
2. However, do the apps within the application centre also need to be certified by apple?

Can anyone help confirm this? or share some insight

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no apps inside the appcenter application. They all reside on a remote server and they never go through Apple.